# What is this weird inconsistency in inverse of $\cos^2x$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have the following equation: $$\cos^2(x)=1$$
And to my knowledge there are two ways to solve for x: 
1) Taking the square root of both sides  and then taking $\arccos(x)$ on both sides
$$\cos(x)=1$$$$x=0$$

2) Taking $\arccos(x)$ twice on both sides, however that leads me with the following answer $$x=90$$
Why is this so, has there been an error in my method ?

Comment: $\arccos (\arccos (\cos^2(x))) \ne x$

Comment: By convention, $\cos^2x$ denotes $(\cos x)^2$, **not** $\cos(\cos x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method $1$ assumes that $\cos^2x$ stands for the number $\cos x$ squared, while method $2$ assumes that it stands for the function $\cos$ applied to $x$ twice in a row. These are far from equivalent, and only the first interpretation is correct.

This being said, you don't solve such an equation by just applying the square root and thank you, good bye. You have to account for the fact that a number can be negative.

Comment: You also need to account that $\cos(x)$ is periodic so the actual solution to $\cos(x)=1$ is $x=180 n°$ where $n$ is some integer.

Comment: "... just applying the square root and thank you, good bye." Great way to phrase it, Arnaud. Gave me a nice laugh.

Comment: @Kyky True, although traditionally when $\cos$ is regarded as a function, $x$ is expressed in radians. atJonathanZ Welcome :)

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yeah, I initially used radians, but since OP used degrees in their question I decided to edit it to use degrees.